# C - Function call itself causes segfault in recursive calls

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, segmentation-fault

Im fighting a segfault error that I can't understand : I have a recursive function that expands on an array representing pixels : starting on an index, it exepands around the index to create groups of pixels by calling the same function left right up and down (aka index -1, index +1...). For debuging purposes, I have a printf call at the very first line of the function, and one just before each of the 4 recursive calls. What I dont get is, I end up with a segfault during the recursion at the recrusive call itself (I get the print that is just before the call, but not the one at function start).

```
void explore(Pixel * array, int j, Tache * cur_pound, int * it, Pixel previous){
    printf("%d\n", j); // I DONT GET THIS PRINT AT LAST RECURSIVE CALL
    // out of bounds
    if(j > sizeX * sizeY)
        return;

    // allready explored index
    if(array[j].explored == 1){
        return;
    }

   // to big of a color difference between this pixel and the reference one
   if(abs((int)array[j].r - previous.r) > SEUIL || abs((int)array[j].g - previous.g) > SEUIL || abs((int)array[j].b - previous.b) > SEUIL){
      return;
   }

   array[j].explored = 1;
   cur_pound->limits[* it] = j;
   (* it)++;

  // recursion
  if(j +1 < sizeX * sizeY && array[j+1].explored != 1){
        printf("before SF\n); // I GET THIS PRINTF
        explore(array, j + 1, cur_pound, it, previous);
  }
  // 3 other recursive calls removed for simplicity here
}
```

About my data structures : a `Tache *` is `struct` that contains 3 GLubytes and `limits`, an `int *` that represents every pixel index that belongs to this group. A `Pixel` contains 3 GLubytes and a `char` that represents if this pixel has already been visited by the function. The `array` given to the function as the first argument is an array of `Pixel` that represent my image. 
`it` is an `int` representing the index in the group so that my function knows where on the array it should add a new index.
`Limits` are initialised at `-1` outside this function and are allocated with `malloc(size * sizeof(int))` where `size` is the width of the image multiplied by its height.

This is how the inital call is done :

```
void taches_de_couleur(Image *i){
    int j, k, y, size, it;
    GLubyte * im;
    Pixel * array;

    sizeX = i->sizeX;
    sizeY = i->sizeY;  
    k = 0;
    size = sizeX * sizeY;
    array = malloc(size * sizeof(Pixel));
    im = i->data;

   /* build the array from image data */
   for(j = 0; j < 3 * size; j+= 3){
       array[k].explored = 0;
       array[k].r = i->data[j];
       array[k].g = i->data[j + 1];
       array[k].b = i->data[j + 2];
       k++;
    }

    Tache * new_pound;
    new_pound = malloc(sizeof(Tache));
    new_pound->limits = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    int x= 0;
    while(x < size){
        new_pound->limits[x] = -1;
        x++;
    }
    it = 0;
    explore(array, 0, new_pound, &it, array[0]);
}
```

Note that the program does not produce any SF when working with small images (biggest i could do was 512x384px).
This thing has been giving me a headache for a week now, can't figure out what is causing this segfault and thats why im asking you guys if you can see anything obvious here. I can add the second function that calls explore if need be, but this part seems to be good.

EDIT : this is the output gdb gives me when I run it with a image too big :

```
Thread 1 "palette" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b730be in __GI___libc_write (fd=1, buf=0x555555592770, 
nbytes=7)
at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c:26
26  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/write.c: No such file or directory.
```

EDIT : Since im failing to provide enough ressources, see https://github.com/BruhP8/TachesDeCouleur for the full project
Thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't given us [enough to reproduce the error](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but it looks as if you've exceeded the limits of the call stack. Each call to `explore` must wait until all the calls it makes have ended, before it can end, and your computer can handle only so many of them at once. If your array is too big, the stack crashes before you reach the edge.

Comment: idk what else to provide to make it easier to understand. Any idea as to how I could reduce stack usage ?

Comment: I don't know how to make my comment easier to understand, You can reduce stack usage by avoiding recursion; that is probably the best approach in this case.

Comment: @Beta, the computer can handle very many occurrences because they are not _executing_ concurrently. However, _the stack_ can _store_ only so many occurrences before it _runs out of stack space_ and the run-time aborts the program, would be a more precise answer.

Comment: I did undertsand you, what I dont get is how I could do this in my case. I need to visit all pixels of my array once... Im already testing if they have been visited, and I exit the function in case the color doesnt match... How could I reduce the amount of calls even more ?

Comment: Maybe it is possible to change your algorithm into a loop.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie wouldn't this require some other kind of stack that would get filled up too ?

Comment: No it won't. Because you eliminate the storage of each recursive call.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie: You're right, I was speaking broadly.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie This would be a lot of work to redo, I'll keep it as a last resort and explore other things first. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I dont get is, I end up with a segfault during the recursion at the recrusive call itself (I get the print that is just before the call, but not the one at function start).

That is an almost sure sign of stack exhaustion.

Run your program under debugger, and examine the *instruction* which causes segfault. Chances are, it will be one of stack manipulation instructions (`CALL`, `PUSH`), or a stack dereference instruction that follows stack decrement. You can also look at the value of `$SP` register, and compare it to the bounds of stack segment (from `/proc/$pid/maps` if you are on Linux).

The code you've shown does not appear to allocate any stack, so the problem is likely in the code you omitted.

> Note that the program does not produce any SF when working with small images

That is another sign: you are probably allocating a new image on the stack, and the larger the image, the fewer levels of recursion you can achieve.

P.S. On Linux, default stack size is often 8MiB. Try `ulimit -s unlimited` -- if that allows the program to recur deeper, that would be a sure sign that my guess is correct. But don't use `ulimit -s unlimited` as a fix (it's not).

**Update:**

With the full source code, I was able to build the `palette` program. Each recursive call to `explore` only takes 48 bytes of stack (which isn't much).

But with default 8MiB stack, that limits the total recursion to `(8 << 20) / 48 == 174762` levels deep.

TL;DR: if your recursive procedure requires one level of recursion *per pixel*, then you would not be able to process large images. You must rewrite the procedure to be iterative instead.

Comment: Ok so the unlimited trick did get it to go much further but still ended up freezing, so I killed it. See my edit for the output of gdb. What could be wrong on the ommited code ? All I have allocated is the cur_pound and its limits array

Comment: @Bruh So you've confirmed that my answer is correct one. But you don't appear to understand how to fix it. "What could be wrong in the omitted code?" -- how can I know without seeing it? You need to show what stack allocations you do there (and eliminate them).

Comment: I edited the post for better readability. I ommited it at first because it makes for a lot of code which is not advised here, sorry

Comment: @Bruh The code you posted doesn't appear to allocate much stack either. The problem is likely *elsewhere*, and if you want help solving it, you will have to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Well unless posting the whole file which would make the post unreadable there is not much more to show. If you want to, I can provide a github link for the whole project... The rest is code provided by my teacher that is essentially gl code that i dont fully understand.

Comment: @Bruh Providing gihub link is a good idea, when you can't make MCVE.

Comment: https://github.com/BruhP8/TachesDeCouleur you can see everything here

Comment: Thanks for your insight and time !

Answer (score 0):

It seems the first boundary check in your code should be:

```
if( j >= sizeX * sizeY )
```

and not

```
if( j > sizeX * sizeY )
```

(As the last element of your array is array[size - 1] and not array[size])

Comment: True, and thanks for pointing this out. Doesn't seem to be the source of the SF tho